# Finding how many members are in a role

Tags: discord.js

How would I find how many members are in a specific role.

```
let memberCount = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Lobby 1").members.size;
```

This only returns 0 or 1 depending on if the user has the role.

Comment: Your code works just fine.

Comment: I'm attempting to find total members in a role. This is only returning whether the user that reacts with the bot has the role or not, not the total count of members within the role.

Comment: what is your `discord.js` version ?. I'm using `^12.5.1`
`client.on('message', msg => {
    const mm = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(r=>r.name==="aupma").members.size;
    console.log(mm);
});`
Above code returns `3` on my test server

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the user list of the server and then loop through the array checking if one of the users has the role. If a user has the role, you can increment a global var.
Hope I could help
ShadowLp174